# Subreport is printing but it is moving to next page when we add more details?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a new sub report it is printing all the details but in main report if I add the more than one details the sub report is going to next page it is  should not happen for me the sub report must be fixed at the same position even if I add more details in main report.I could not fix this problem.Please suggest me.

Main report:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="esr-design-40" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="326"/>
<scriptlet name="esrgenerator" class="dk.comtalk.billing.server.util.ESRGenerator"/>
<parameter name="printAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityLogo" class="java.io.File"/>
<parameter name="countryCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="balance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="carriedBalance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="statusChangeDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="totalWithTax" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="newStatusId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="invoiceInfoList" class="java.util.List"/>
<parameter name="ESRTotal" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ravi Workspace\\Openbrm\\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\\resources\\designs\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select count(*) from payment_invoice p where p.invoice_id=$P{invoiceId};]]>
</queryString>
<field name="payment_count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<group name="invoice_total">
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<title>
    <band height="430">
        <image>
            <reportElement x="8" y="0" width="185" height="48" />
            <imageExpression class="java.io.File"><![CDATA[$P{entityLogo}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="120" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="148" width="294" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="162" width="211" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="134" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="384" y="103" width="200" height="28" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[1. opomena za neizmireni racun]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="230" width="328" height="19" />
            <text><![CDATA[Postovani gospodine/postovana gospodjo,]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="250" width="544" height="35" />
            <text><![CDATA[Dozvolite da Vas podsetimo da je, po podacima naseg knjigovodstva od danasnjeg dana, sledeci telefonski racun jos otvoren:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="346" width="549" height="34" />
            <text><![CDATA[Ukoliko je Vasa uplata za ovde navedeni racun u medjuvremenu vec izvrsena, nemojte uzimati ovu opomenu u obzir. Ukoliko jos nije, molimo Vas da uplatu izvrsite odmah.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="370" width="557" height="60" />
            <text><![CDATA[Imajte u vidu da se kod opomena, uz regularni racun, placa administrativna taksa za obradu u visini od Fr. 20.00. Ev. deaktivacija servisa se, takodje, naplacuje dodatnih Fr. 20.00. Molimo Vas stoga za postovanje nasih rokova uplate.

    Najlepse hvala.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="405" y="173" width="134" height="14" />
            <text><![CDATA[Wangen b. Brüttisellen,]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="510" y="173" width="100" height="15" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy").parse($P{statusChangeDate}))]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="37" y="274" width="556" height="55" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" />
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{invoiceInfoList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="117">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="101" width="576" height="16" />
            <text><![CDATA[Symphonica AG | Hegnaustrasse 17 | 8602 Wangen b. Brüttisellen | Telefon 0840 988 988 | Fax 043 536 05 43]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="8" width="243" height="26" />
            <text><![CDATA[S postovanjem,
           BALKATEL | Symphonica A.D.]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<summary>
    <band height="294" splitType="Immediate">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="592" height="109" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" />
            <subreportParameter name="ESRTotal">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ESRTotal}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="entityCity">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityCity}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="customerName">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceDate">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="customerProvince">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerProvince}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="countryCode">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="statusChangeDate">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{statusChangeDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="customerCity">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerCity}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceDueDate">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceDueDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="newStatusId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{newStatusId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="customerPostalCode">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="entityName">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="balance">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{balance}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="entityPostalCode">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityPostalCode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="customerId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="printAmount">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{printAmount}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="entityAddress">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityAddress}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="entityProvince">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityProvince}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="customerAddress">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="carriedBalance">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{carriedBalance}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="totalWithTax">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{totalWithTax}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="entityLogo">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityLogo}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceInfoList">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceInfoList}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ageing-esr-40-srpski-ESR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
    </summary>
   </jasperReport>
```

subreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="esr-design-40" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<scriptlet name="esrgenerator" class="dk.comtalk.billing.server.util.ESRGenerator"/>
<parameter name="printAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityLogo" class="java.io.File"/>
<parameter name="countryCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="balance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="carriedBalance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="statusChangeDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="totalWithTax" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="newStatusId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="invoiceInfoList" class="java.util.List"/>
<parameter name="ESRTotal" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ravi Workspace\\Openbrm\\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\\resources\\designs\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select count(*) from payment_invoice p where p.invoice_id=$P{invoiceId};]]>
</queryString>
<group name="invoice_total">
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<title>
    <band height="430"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="117"/>
</pageHeader>
<summary>
    <band height="294">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="56" width="123" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="68" width="153" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="81" width="226" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityPostalCode}+ " " + $P{entityCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="5" y="26" width="100" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[6301 Zug]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="179" y="26" width="100" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[6301 Zug]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="56" width="123" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="68" width="149" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="81" width="226" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityPostalCode}+ " " + $P{entityCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="97" y="110" width="100" height="14" />
            <text><![CDATA[01-2653-5]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="272" y="110" width="100" height="16" />
            <text><![CDATA[01-2653-5]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="169" y="236" width="640" height="30" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="13"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.generateCodeline($P{ESRTotal}.split("\\s+")[1],"01",">","971786","+","0126535",">",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="132" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="144" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="158" width="294" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="193" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="205" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="218" width="251" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="172" width="211" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="230" width="194" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="92" width="424" height="19" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.getReferenceNumber("971786",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="172" width="186" height="16" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.getReferenceNumber("971786",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="132" y="142" width="47" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{ESRTotal}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[1])]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="301" y="142" width="40" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{ESRTotal}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[1])]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="2" y="142" width="105" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{ESRTotal}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[0]).trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="173" y="142" width="105" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{ESRTotal}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[0]).trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
 </summary>
 </jasperReport>
```

Comment: @Alex nobody has answered for my question if it is a duplicate it could not help me then you say the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please refer "split type" , current page is not enough for the sub report to display.